# How to Get Rid of These Extra Spaces?

Tags: java, loops

This program asks to list out all the possible years which are leap years from 2014 to 2114, which I did correctly in the program shown below and the years to be listed with a space in each with 10 in every row. Once 10 years are listed, you go to the next. line. The only problem which I notice is that there are 3 empty lines between every 10 rows of years. How can I alter the program so there are no spaces between these rows.

```
public class fiveTwoSeven {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int year2 = 2114;
        int count = 0;
        for (int year1 = 2014; year1 <= year2; year1++)
        {
            if (year1 % 4 == 0 && !(year1 % 100 == 0))
            {
                System.out.print(year1 + " ");
                count++;
            }
            if (count % 10 == 0 && !(count == 0))
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So count only changes on a leap year, but you print the new line every year that count is satisfied?

Comment: No, sorry I should have specified in the question, but you print a new line for every ten leap years.

Comment: Move the second `if` statement into first. `count++; if(count % 10 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only `println()` in your `if` block (since that is when you output leap years). More importantly, your algorithm has a bug. Years that are multiples of 400 **are** leap years (`2000` and `2400` are both leap years). I suggest you save the leap year as a local `boolean`. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0, year1 = 2014, year2 = 2114;
    for (; year1 <= year2; year1++) {
        boolean leapYear = false;
        if (year1 % 4 == 0) {
            if (year1 % 100 != 0) {
                leapYear = true;
            } else if (year1 % 400 == 0) {
                leapYear = true;
            }
        }
        if (leapYear) {
            System.out.print(year1 + " ");
            count++;
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick Question, how does your for loop work?  I see its missing its first condition.

Comment: @SohamSamantaray I moved `year1` declaration and initialization to the previous statement (with `year2`). It makes more sense to me to put both in the same place. You can have an entirely empty initialization, test and increment operation in a (infinite) `for` loop. That is, `for(;;)` is like `while(true)` - anyway, use whichever you find ***easiest*** to read.

Comment: @SohamSamantaray You made me think about it some more, and we can improve your algorithm quite a bit. You only need to find the first leap year. Every four years after that is another one.

Comment: Using your second algorithmically improved solution 2100 is a leap year.

Comment: @Oleg Good point. Removed it. 2100 is not a leap year, but 2096 is. I'll be 123. Or dead. Probably the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
if (count % 10 == 0 && !(count == 0))
{
  System.out.println();
  count = 0;
}
```

Or

```
    int year2 = 2114;
    int count = 0;
    for (int year1 = 2014; year1 <= year2; year1++)
    {
        if (year1 % 4 == 0 && !(year1 % 100 == 0))
        {
            count++;
            System.out.print(year1 + " ");
            if(count % 10 == 0 && !(count == 0)) {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

1. You just need to reset the value of `count` after it reaches to `10` so that cursor goes to the next line.

Comment: What happened to 2052 and 2092?

Comment: @Oleg thanks for finding the issue. I have updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your second if condition block to this:

```
if (count % 10 == 0 && !(count == 0))
{
    System.out.println();
    count = 0;
}
```

It is creating problem when count is 10 or 20 or 30 or ....

I am giving explanation for 10...

From 2014, according to your logic 10th leap year is 2052. So after printing 2052, you are printing a new line. And for 2053, 2054 and 2055, your count is still 10. So second if block is printing another new line for each one.